# Calculate centroids in memory from polygon using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

I need to calculate Centroids from polygon layer without reading and writing shapefiles. 
I tried this code in python console (QGIS 3):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
params = {'INPUT': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer.id(), True),'ALL_PARTS':False,'OUTPUT': 'memory:'}
newLayer = processing.run("native:centroids", params)
layerOutput = newLayer['OUTPUT']
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerOutput)
```

There are no error's messages and the new layer has the right fields, but there are not features, it's empty. If I run the algorithm using processing toolbox it works. 
Where is the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using in following way is enough.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

params = {'INPUT': layer, 
          'ALL_PARTS':False,
          'OUTPUT': 'memory:'}

newLayer = processing.run("native:centroids", params)
layerOutput = newLayer['OUTPUT']
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerOutput)
```